# Can't install iPy on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to install iPy, but I can't seem to do it right. This is the first time I install a module, so please don't assume I should be knowing some things.
I downloaded the file, and I have a setup.py. I held down Shift+Right Click, then "open Command Prompt Here", and pasted the following line :

`python setup.py --help` or `python setup.py install`

It says that it is not recognized as an internal command.

I tried opening it in python and running it, and I get this error:

```
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied
```

I also tried to paste `python setup.py --help` and `python setup.py install` in the python console, and I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "T:\MATH\Logiciels MATH BD\Program Files\EduPython\App\lib\code.py", line 63, in runsource
    code = self.compile(source, filename, symbol)
  File "T:\MATH\Logiciels MATH BD\Program Files\EduPython\App\lib\codeop.py", line 168, in __call__
    return _maybe_compile(self.compiler, source, filename, symbol)
  File "T:\MATH\Logiciels MATH BD\Program Files\EduPython\App\lib\codeop.py", line 99, in _maybe_compile
    raise err1
  File "T:\MATH\Logiciels MATH BD\Program Files\EduPython\App\lib\codeop.py", line 87, in _maybe_compile
    code1 = compiler(source + "\n", filename, symbol)
  File "T:\MATH\Logiciels MATH BD\Program Files\EduPython\App\lib\codeop.py", line 133, in __call__
    codeob = compile(source, filename, symbol, self.flags, 1)
  File "<interactive input>", line 1
    python setup.py --help
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How am I supposed to install it ?

EDIT: A screenshot of what I get:
[image: screenshot]

EDIT2: 2nd screenshot:
[image: scren]

Comment: are you trying in linux or windows

Comment: Do you have python in your PATH variable?

Comment: try `pip install ipy`  if you downloaded it then try `pip install your-directory-path-here`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this code in a Python shell (i.e. one where you can run Python commands, for example the Python GUI) to get the location of your installed Python:

```
import sys
sys.executable
```

This will give you the complete path to the Python interpreter.

Then, in command prompt (Shift-Right Click where the setup.py is located and open Command Prompt) specify the complete path to Python like this:

```
"C:\Python36\python.exe" setup.py install
```

Or whatever your path is.

Comment: Still doesn't work I posted a screenshot of what I do in case I'm doing something wrong

Comment: @MegzariNassim open **Command Prompt** in the folder where setup.py is, and type `T:\MATH\Logiciels MATH BD\Program Files\EduPython\App\python.exe setup.py install`. Make sure you are in the folder where setup.py is and type it in Command prompt, not PyScripter!

Comment: Still nothing it says not identified as an internal command (screenshot in post, and it's in french)

Comment: @MegzariNassim Surround the path to python.exe in double quotes. It should now work… `"T:\MATH\Logiciels MATH BD\Program Files\EduPython\App\python.exe" setup.py install`

Comment: It worked thank you now I know how to install a library.

Comment: @MegzariNassim Please consider upvoting and accepting this answer if it helped you.

Comment: I reached my daily limit for voting but I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you don't have Python in your `$PATH`, in that case you need to explicitly write the full path to your Python install, because your shell doesn't know where to find `python`. For Python 3.6 under Windows that'd probably be `C:\Python36\python.exe` (or whatever you chose when installing it).

Hence, to install iPython, run:

```
C:\Python36\python.exe setup.py install
```

Comment: I did this and it gives me a syntax error on the first character of my path: `T:\MATH\Logiciels MATH BD\Program Files\EduPython\python.exe setup.py install`

Comment: @MegzariNassim try forward slash

Comment: @MegzariNassim well what is the ‘syntax error’? Please elaborate in your question.

Comment: It gives me a syntax error on the first character of the path wich means in `T:\MATH\Logiciels MATH BD\Program Files\EduPython\python.exe setup.py install` it is on `T:`

Comment: You need to run it in your regular shell, not from within Python.

Answer (score 1):

`setup.py` is designed to be run from the command line. You'll need to open your command prompt (In Windows 7, hold down shift while right-clicking in the directory with the `setup.py` file. You should be able to select "Open Command Window Here").

From the command line, you can type

```
python setup.py --help
```

If you want to install it then the command is install:

```
python setup.py install
```

If you need to build the package first, use the build command before installing:

```
python setup.py build
```

Hope this helps!

> HELP:you need more details use this [link](https://docs.python.org/3/install/index.html).

Even the above commands may not work correctly. In that case, you can download the [Windows installer version](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyglet) which will install the library to your default system Python

Comment: Because the questioner clearly indicates that he is using Windows. Also the question is about installing from setup.py, **not** from pip.

Comment: kk i will the answer

Comment: @Rishav That never means that OP doesn't need an `pip install` method,

Comment: @Rishav He edited the answer, So Please remove his down vote also.